# How do I configure my own shortcuts in Auctex (Emacs)?

Tags: key-bindings, init-file, auctex

I have a problem that I could not solve with the help of google.

a) How do I have to adjust the .emacs file in order to use the Windows-Key (Super-Key) for shortcuts. I am working on a Linux system and the system does not use this key.

b) How do I create my own shortcuts using this key – I am sure that I have to do that in the .emacs file also but I haven’t found out exactly how to do it. The reason why I want to do all this is, that I a recently switched from TeXstudio to Autctex and I want to use (at least till I am getting used to the Emacs/Auctex World) as many of my old shortcuts (For: begin{quote}, section, italics, footnote etc.

So I want:

Win + i = Italics

Win + b = Bold

Win + Z = Quote

Win + F12 = begin{itemize}

Win + 1 = section

etc. etc.

If I should move the questions elsewhere I would be glad to do it…

Comment: You're probably looking to bind the [super key](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/07/17/make-use-of-the-super-key/) (also see [this tutorial](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_hyper_super_keys.html)).

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example of what you want to accomplish:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load "latex"
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "s-z")
    (lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (LaTeX-insert-environment "quote")))
  (define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "s-<f12>")
    (lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (LaTeX-insert-environment "itemize"))))
```

But please note that if you want to unleash the power of AUCTeX, you shouldn't try to mimic the shortcuts of other editors but exploit the default key-bindings.  Thus, for example, you can insert the all font-related commands with <kbd>C-c C-f C-X</kbd>, where <kbd>X</kbd> is a different letter for each different font command (<kbd>E</kbd> for `\emph`, <kbd>b</kbd> for `\textbf`, etc... issue <kbd>C-c C-f C-h</kbd> for the complete list).  This is much more powerful than what you may expect because it's context-sensitive, it lets you insert the appropriate macro depending on whether you're in plain-TeX or LaTeX mode and on whether you're inside or outside an equation, always with the same key-bindings.

In the same way, <kbd>C-c C-s</kbd> lets you insert a new sectioning command, there is no need to specify a different key-binding for it.

Any environment can be inserted with <kbd>C-c C-e</kbd>, which provides sensible default choices.

Any macro can be inserted with <kbd>C-c C-m</kbd> (or <kbd>C-c RET</kbd>), with a powerful autocompletion mechanism for the most common commands (more than 200 packages are supported).

Comment: Good answer, but I do find the `C-c C-f C-X` bindings really tedious. My professional writing includes lots of italicized words, so binding `C-c i` is a big improvement over the default key chain.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am about to learn these commands but I only use Latex for "normal" Texts (no math etc.). One last thing: the two examples you gave are for environments. But how is the code when it comes to the change of fonts (to italics etc) and how when it comes to section? Or is section an environment?

Comment: To change an already present font command: `C-u C-c C-f C-X`.  To change an already present environment: `C-u C-c C-e`.  In these cases, you usually need to prefix the key-binding with `C-u`.